# How to add Bit torrent analyzer to bro IDS

Tags: bro

I have to analyze some pcap files using bro IDS. It have a lot of built in analyzer. I have to enable bit torrrent analyzer. Its details are give [here](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/script-reference/proto-analyzers.html#bro-bittorrent). How I have enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load it using the @load statement: try.bro.org/#/?example=basics-loading