# Is there any P2P analyzer in bro ids

Tags: wireshark, libpcap, traffic, bro

I have to analyze few pcap files. I have installed bro 2.5. It works perfectly. But It does not give any information (e.g. data transfer, peers) about p2p connections like torrent etc. Is their any builtin option?

Please give some example (configuration etc.) about it as I am newbie in Bro IDS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get output related to a certain protocol, you need to load the correct protocol analyzer. P2P is a networking principle, not a protocol by itself. There have been many different P2P protocols and protocol implementations in the past. Bro has an analyzer (although still in beta-version) for Bit-Torrent. I don't know if there is one for any other P2P protocol, you can scan through: https://www.bro.org/sphinx/script-reference/proto-analyzers.html.
You can always write your own analyzer, find a start here:
https://www.bro.org/sphinx/components/binpac/README.html.

You asked similar questions before, e.g., here: [How to add Bit torrent analyzer to bro IDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323672/how-to-add-bit-torrent-analyzer-to-bro-ids?rq=1). In this questions I explain - with example - how to load an analyzer.

It might be more helpful for you if you didn't start a new question for this same topic over and over again but explain why my other answers didn't help you and ask follow up questions.